# How do you limit number of connected users on MultipeerConnectivity in Swift?

Tags: swift, multipeer-connectivity

How do you limit the number of connected peers on the MultipeerConnectivity Framework in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Invite peers to join the session using an MCNearbyServiceBrowser object, an MCBrowserViewController object, or your own peer discovery code. (Sessions currently support up to 8 peers, including the local peer.)
https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity/mcsession

Comment: I want only to allow two people to join

Comment: Once two users have connected via the delegate method, turn off the browser or reject new connections.